# How was Nora related to Judy and Peter?

Tags: jumanji

Early in *Jumanji* (1995) we learn Judy and Peter's parents died in an accident while they were young. Instead, the children were raised by a woman named Nora.

I don't remember the film explaining who Nora was, or why she presumably adopted Judy and Peter.

Is Nora’s relation with Judy and Peter ever explained?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

She is Peter and Judy's aunt.

> "Wait!  The instructions say if we finish the game it'll all go away.  We'd better do it, or Aunt Nora's going to pitch a fit."

--- *Jumanji*, 1995, circa 27:50

According to various online references ([IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113497/characters/nm0001564?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t6), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumanji#Plot), [Google](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=jumanji%201995%20cast)) her full name is Nora Shepherd, which would make her their father's sister.

Comment: Is that quote from Judy or Peter?

Comment: The quote is from Judy.

Answer (score 14):

Nora says:

> That sounds lovely. I'm sure you and your kids are gonna be very happy here.
>
> **Oh. Well, actually, they're my late brother's**. He and his wife passed away just last winter.

So, she is their aunt on their father's side.

Comment: It's around about the 16 minute mark, when Nora is talking to the estate agent.